# Seeking lake to paddle board at Mt Baker, Glacier, WA

Tags: water-sports, lakes, washington-state

I'm going to visit Glacier, WA for vacation and will stay there for a few days. I plan to bring my stand up paddleboard with me, and would like to know if it's allowed to paddleboard on lakes there, and is there any lake recommendation.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What particular lakes do you have in mind?

Comment: not sure if it's allowed in picture lake for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Picture Lake was mentioned in a comment.  According to the USDA Forest Service, swimming and boating is not permitted on [Picture Lake](https://www.fs.usda.gov/recarea/mbs/recarea/?recid=17536) (my emphasis)

> Picture Lake is the centerpiece of a strikingly beautiful landscape in
> the Heather Meadows area.
>
> ...
>
> Hikers only. No camping. No fires, except self-contained, carry-in
> stoves. No snowmobiles. Dogs must be leashed within the developed
> recreation area of Heather Meadows. **Swimming and boating prohibited**.
> Do not enter areas closed for rehabilitation.

I'd guess that you'd need to consider your SUP on a case by case basis as determined by the Forest Service.  However I think your best bet for identifying lakes where you can SUP is to find those that have a boat ramp.